# Masculine vs feminine adjectives when used with first person verbs

Tags: adjetivos

I've been taking Spanish lessons through Duolingo and came across a question where a girl says "I sleep alone and eat alone." and you are asked to select the options for which is correct. It gave two answers that it says are correct:

- "Yo duermo sola y como sola." **<-- I chose this one.**
- "Yo duermo solo y como solo." **<-- but this one was also listed as correct**

Can either gender properly say either of those statements? Or should feminine/masculine speakers use their appropriate adjectives?

Comment: It's worth to mention that it's not necessary to write the same word twice: *yo duermo y como sola(o).* (It's clear that you also sleep alone.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spanish the 90% of adjectives has masculine and feminine gender. If you are a male, you have to choose the second option:

> Yo duermo solo y como solo

If you are female you have to choose the first one:

> Yo duermo sola y como sola

This is one of the most difficult things for foreigners, choose the right gender appropriately.

I'll try to give you a useful clue that will help you:

- Gender male: adjective normally ends with `-e`, `-i`, `-o`, `-u` (in singular) and `-es`, `-is`, `-os` and `-us` (in plural). In your case (assuming that you are a male, you have to choose one of this, `solo` to be exact)
- Female gender: adjective normally ended with `-a` (in singular) and `-as` (in plural).

If you want more information I can edit the post and give you some examples or expand some parts to give you more information.

Hope it helps!